# oLog is the object of which class?

Tags: apache, logging, pega

I am a `PEGA` developer and we have an `object oLog` created for logging messages into our log files. We are trying to figure out from which class was this object created? All these classes belong to `Apache4J` Logger.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out by executing

```
oLog.debug(oLog.getClass().getName());
```

and read the information from the logfile (assuming it's log level is set to debug).